# Why when using EhCache, CPU reaches to 100%?

Tags: hibernate, caching, cpu, ehcache

I use EhCache Hibernate Second Level Cache for and Query Caching.
Everything is fine, but the CPU I have 100 per cent up to 10 users via the JMeter.
If you disable the EhCache, then CPU becomes appropriate.
Anyone have any opinions on this?
So instead of improving performance, EhCache loaded my CPU.

It's my dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance "
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
         name="cacheManager"
         monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="user.home/ehcacheEntriesStore" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="100" eternal="false"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="10" timeToLiveSeconds="10" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
                  maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="1200"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="false">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="serviceCache"
        maxBytesLocalHeap="500M"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        maxElementsOnDisk="1000"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

    <cache  name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="50000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToLiveSeconds="300">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>
    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="50000" eternal="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

persistence.xml

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
              value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
              value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="ehcache.xml"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy" value="transactional"/>
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4"/>
    <property name="hibernate.auto_close_session" value="true"/>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>-->
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="30" />

    <!--<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>-->
    <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true"/>-->

</properties
```

>

Comment: In general, that's good news, you have reached almost ideal CPU utilization. :) However, if this is slowing your application down, then you should investigate it with a profiler and update the question with your findings.

Comment: I'm use profiler end find next http://snag.gy/kRpDI.jpg  .

Answer (score 0):

For Ehcache 3.x, it is a bug.
The cache statistics threadpool is creating a new thread for every statistics. So the thread itself is doing very less work, but OS is consuming most CPU to create that thread.

It is to be fixed in later releases, but temporary workaround is to set the system property `org.ehcache.statisticsExecutor.poolSize` to `1`

Ref: https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/387